# JQuery Slideout only works on one side of the page?

Tags: jquery, css

I've been working on a little slideout code and it's just been impossible. It works perfectly sliding out from the right of the page but when I reverse everything and have it slide from the left, not a chance!

The exact issue is that it slides out farther than the width of it's container.

Example at http://demindu.com/sandbox/slideout/. I'd certainly appreciate any tips in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

> div.sub-menu-content {
>     position:relative;
>     background:url(../img/sub-menu.png) 0
>   0 no-repeat;  width:300px;
>     height:40px;    color:#FFF;
>     font-weight:bolder; }

To this:

> div.sub-menu-content {
>     position:absolute;  right: 0;
>     background:url(../img/sub-menu.png) 0
>   0 no-repeat;  width:300px;
>     height:40px;    color:#FFF;
>     font-weight:bolder; }

Then you'll need to look at the code that gives the div "sub-menu-slide rinner" a margin-right of 275px. Make that come out as 250px instead, and you should be back on track.

Comment: Amazing, thanks for taking the time out of your day to get me unstuck.

Comment: You're welcome. It's high time I started paying the people here back anyway!